# Applescript, POSIX filenames and Mountain Lion

Tags: applescript, posix

While I was using Snow Leopard, I've used many times the following pattern when creating my Applescripts:

```
on run args
    set filePath to POSIX file (item 1 of args) as alias
        ...
end run
```

After upgrading to Mountain Lion, the above script seems to produce a warning, though:

```
2012-08-10 15:12:12.305 osascript[54131:303]
CFURLGetFSRef was passed this URL which has no scheme
(the URL may not work with other CFURL routines): path/to/input/file.ext
```

Could anyone enlighten on the meaning of the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should clarify the problem and solution.  So first *with* the problem

```
TB1T-Bboot:$ cat tmp.applescript
tell application "Finder"
        set MacOSpath to POSIX file "test-file" as alias
end tell
TB1T-Bboot:$ osascript tmp.applescript
2012-09-24 22:25:50.022 osascript[2564:707] CFURLGetFSRef was passed this URL which has no scheme (the URL may not work with other CFURL routines): test-file
alias TB1T-Bboot:Users:archive:test-file
TB1T-Bboot:$
```

Now without the problem:

```
TB1T-Bboot:$ cat tmp.applescript
tell application "Finder"
        set MacOSpath to POSIX file "/Users/archive/test-file" as alias
end tell
TB1T-Bboot:$ osascript tmp.applescript
alias TB1T-Bboot:Users:archive:test-file
TB1T-Bboot:$
```

So it's complaining that the path is relative, not absolute.  This warning doesn't come up in Lion.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix would be to prefix the path with `file:///`.  Mountain Lion expects URLs for everything, so a 'naked' path won't work.

For example, if you want `/Users/RobertoAloi/file.txt you would pass in`file:///Users/RobertoAloi/file.txt`.

The details for CFURLGetFSRef can be found at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Would Snow Leopard complain about the prefix? Cannot test it anymore, given I did the switch to ML.

Comment: Also, that doesn't seem to work for me, but I'm probably prefixing it in the wrong way. Could you please make an example?